# Jquery: append to div with a class that has a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, append

So I'm working on a quick app that when you press a button, dog pictures show up. I want the pictures to appear in rows. So I started to create divs with the class `'dog row'` and ended the name with a variable. 
While the creation of that div is successful. I can't seem to append anything to the div itself.

```
for (i=0; i<dogPool.length; i++){
            if (i%5 == 0){
            $('.dogTable').append(
                "<div class='dogLine dogRow" + rowNumber + "'></div>"
            );
            console.log("<div class='dogLine dogRow" + rowNumber + "'></div>");

                rowName = "'.dogRow" + rowNumber + "'";
                rowNumber++;
            }
            console.log("row: " + rowName);
            $(rowName).append(
                "<p>"+ i + "</p>"
            );
        }
```

Comment: You don't need the single quotes in `rowName`. Just use `rowName = ".dogRow" + rowNumber;`

Comment: Could you please give us your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `rowName = "'.dogRow" + rowNumber + "'";`

You should fix like this

```
 var rowName = '.dogRow' + rowNumber;
```

```js
var dogPool = ["dog1", "dog2"];
var rowNumber = 0;
for (i=0; i<dogPool.length; i++){
    $('.dogTable').append(
        "<div class='dogLine dogRow" + rowNumber + "'></div>"
    );
    console.log("<div class='dogLine dogRow" + rowNumber + "'></div>");

    var rowName = '.dogRow' + rowNumber;
    rowNumber++;
    
    $(rowName).append(
        "<p>"+ i + "</p>"
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dogTable">
123
</div>
```